# Dummy FCM Tokens

Tags: node.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, backend, deviceid

I need a dummy FCM token and dummy mobile ID for testing purposes. I have developed the backend for a social media app and want to test my FCM notification service, but I haven't developed the frontend yet. Is there a way to generate dummy FCM tokens or mobile IDs?

The FCM token is generated exclusively on the frontend, not the backend. It's not possible to directly generate an FCM token on the backend.